# Find a fundamental group of $X=\{z\in \mathbb{C} : 1 \leqslant |z| \leqslant 2\} / _{\sim} $

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

$X =\{z\in \mathbb{C} : 1 \leqslant |z| \leqslant 2\}$. Find a fundamental group of $X /_{\sim} $, where $z_{1} \sim z_{2}$ if and only if $[(|z_{1}| = |z_{2}| = 1$ and $(\frac{z_{1}}{z_{2}})^{3} = 1) $ or $( |z_{1}| = |z_{2}| = 2$ and $(\frac{z_{1}}{z_{2}})^{4} = 1)$ or ($z_{1}=z_{2})]$.

> (It was edited - firstly I wrote an incorrect definition of X.)

I was trying to do it similarly as how you find a fundamental group of $\mathbb{R}P_{2}$ and it goes like this:
$(|z_{1}| = |z_{2}| = 1$ and $(\frac{z_{1}}{z_{2}})^{3} = 1)$ if and only if $z_{1},z_{2} \in S(0,1)$ and the difference between their arguments equals $\frac{\pi}{3}$, whereas $ (|z_{1}| = |z_{2}| = 2$ and $(\frac{z_{1}}{z_{2}})^{4} = 1)$ if and only if $z_{1},z_{2} \in S(0,2)$ and the difference between their arguments equals $\frac{\pi}{4}$. So the only nontrivial equivalence classes are on $S(0,1)$ and $S(0,2)$. Images of those circles in $p: X \rightarrow X/_{\sim} $ are also circles, let name them $S_1$ and $S_2$ respectively. Now we can treat $X/_{\sim}$ as $X\cup_{f}(S_{1}\cup S_{2})$, where f is the restriction of p.

There is a lemma which says that if $Z=\bar{B^{2}} \cup_{f} Y$ where $f: S^{1} \rightarrow Y$ is a continuous map, then for $y=f(1)$, $i: Y \rightarrow Z$ enduces an epimorphism $i_{*}: \pi_{1}(Y,y) \rightarrow \pi_{1}(Z,y)$ with kernel $<<[\lambda_{f}]>>$, where $[\lambda_{f}]$ is a path such that for $t \in I=[0,1]$ we have $t \mapsto f(\exp(2 \pi i t)) \in Y$. Moreover, if $<S,R>$ is the presentation for $\pi_{1}(Y,y)$, then $<S|R\cup \{[\lambda_{f}]\}>$ is the presentation of $\pi_{1}(Z,y)$.

Is it possible to use those fact in some tricky way in my problem?

Comment: It seems that you have an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $X$. But either the definition of $X$ is not correct or $z_1 \sim z_2$ iff $z_1 = z_2$.

Comment: $X$ is defined as the ring $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : 1 < |z| < 2 \}$. Then we make a quotient space using the relation $\sim$, which has three types of equivalence classes. I'm not sure why it should be $z_{1} \sim z_{2}$ iff $z_{1} = z_{2}$?

Comment: Because if $z_1 \ne z_2$ you must  have either $\lvert z_i \rvert =1$ or $\lvert z_i \rvert =2$. These points are not contained in $X$.

Comment: I guess you mean $X =\{z\in \mathbb{C} : 1 \le |z| \le 2\} /
_{\sim} $.

Comment: Oh sure, now I see, thanks! Of course $X= \{z \in \mathbb{C} : 1 \leqslant |z| \leqslant 2\}$.  I'll edit it in a moment.

Comment: Can you use your lemma as stated by first applying it to the same with $W = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \; | 0 \leq |z| \leq 2 \}$ and then applying Van-Kampen?

Comment: But how do you want to apply it for $W$? You mean for $W / _{\sim}$? I'm not sure how to represent it as the union of subsets properly.